# I need Split String in java?

Tags: java, string, split

I have String like `String str = "Abhishek Patel(123121)";` Nd I want Split String in two part.

```
String Name = "Abhishek Patel"; 
String ID = 123121;
```

i had tried like this in in java

```
String str = "Abhishek Patel(123121)";

    String a[] = str.split("(");
    String Name =a[0];
```

Comment: Or use a regex? Substring/indexOf?

Comment: why would you please on `)` - there is nothing after that

Comment: every time i have different String like this so i cant use IndexOf/Substring.

Comment: @AbhishekPatel Why not? Find the index of '(' and ')'?

Comment: check my answer please.

Comment: Very unclear question, why can't you use split() first and then search for and remove the ')' after? This looks like such a trivial problem that has many possible solutions.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use a combination of split and substring

```
    String name = "Abhishek Patel(1234567)"; 
    String[] parts = name.split("\\(");
    System.out.println(parts[0]);
    System.out.println(parts[1].substring(0, parts[1].length() -1));
```

As @JoakimDanielson has correctly pointed out, if the last `)` is optional then it maybe be better to use replace rather than substring

```
System.out.println(parts[1].replace(")", ""));
```

Comment: Shouldn't you at least check that the last character is a ')'?

Comment: @JoakimDanielson Not sure what you are asking.  The OP has stated what the string is.  If the last `)` is optional then it would be a different question and could easily be fixed by using `replace(")", "")`  Do I have to also believe that the first `(` is also optional?

Comment: The OP hasn't stated much, so I wouldn't assume much. But maybe I'm being fooled by thinking this question is so simple to solve that there much be something else to it.

Comment: @JoakimDanielson I have updated my answer with you concerns

Answer (score 3):

Take advantage of two facts.

1. The `split` method by default throws away any empty strings that appear after the matches.
2. You don't need to escape `(` or `)` if they appear in `[]` characters in a regular expression.

So you can just write this.

```
String toSplit = "Abishek Patel(12345)";
String[] parts = toSplit.split("[()]");
```

This gives an array of only two elements, not three, and they are the name and id.

Comment: Now we just need to educate the OP as to which answer to accept

Comment: @ScaryWombat maybe Abishek took the word "check" in Sagar's comment under the question to mean "tick".

Answer (score -2):

Try this. will help you

```
    String str = "Abhishek Patel(123121)";

    String a[] = str.replace("(", "  ").replace(")", "  ").split("  ");
    String Name =a[0];
    String id =a[1];
    System.out.println(Name);
    System.out.println(id);
```

EDIT-------------

as suggested by Scary Wombat that there could be 2 spaces in the name it self. You can change this to something else.
The basic idea was to remove the unwanted and boundry characters with one common and split then.

Thanks @ScaryWombat.

Comment: why do a replace first?

Comment: Thanks Got ans Thanks !

Comment: @DawoodibnKareem : I actually did

Comment: @ScaryWombat : to split string at once. Let say if one more attribute is added in the string then probably that ll help. Futuristic approach.

Comment: The OP has stated that he wants to split based upon brackets.  Your approach would fail if there was another space between `Abhishek` and `Patel`

Comment: correct then we can do something like this 

`String a[] = str.replace(")", ")").split(")");`

Comment: Only if you want `Exception in thread "main" java.util.regex.PatternSyntaxException: Unmatched closing ')'`

Comment: My apologies - I didn't see the doubled up spaces.  However, as others have pointed out, this is kind of flakey.  My opinion is that Wombat's answer is better.

Comment: yea. i mean the The basic idea was to remove the unwanted and boundry characters with one common and split then.

That's the logic. Code is upto you. You can test for scenarios

Comment: @DawoodibnKareem : I don't deny with that. his answer is definitely correct. however I just gave a different opinion. I hope that could be helpful

Comment: Sure.  I didn't downvote you.  And my earlier comment was based on the fact that I read `"  "` as just one space, not two.

Comment: @DawoodibnKareem : haha np. I wasn't worried much about it.